# Haskell Vector: not scientific, engineering vectors?

Tags: haskell, vector

When I see Haskell's Vector, that's not a physics, linear algebra vector, is it? Vectors in Java (as I recall) is an array one can dynamically add to. But that's not usable as a science vector, is it? How could I have a science vector data structure in Haskell?

Comment: What do you mean by vector? Please be specific...

Comment: First you're going to need a way to get science numbers in Haskell. It unfortunately only has limited-precision numeric types, not actual real numbers or complex numbers like science does. This could be a good reason to create a science-to-haskell compiler.

Comment: To make a "Math" vector you just need a type with two fields: magnitude and direction. Is this what you mean?

Comment: [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) might interest you.

Comment: I would be surprised if on Hackage there isn't already a package defining a vector type with the usual linear operations. I'm not familiar with such packages, but surely a linear algebra package is present.

Comment: @MasterMastic This seems to be the boy. Thanks.

Comment: @LawrenceBottorff Great, I'll post it as an answer in a moment with some extra details.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to [`Data.Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector/docs/Data-Vector.html), and yes, you're right. It's not the vector the mathematical parts of us know. For a "legit" vector and any other linear algebra on free vector spaces there is the [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) package.

[`Data.Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector/docs/Data-Vector.html) is pretty much a memory array (very optimized, very good API).

---

[`Data.Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector/docs/Data-Vector.html) really is a misleading name, and I assume it's directly or indirectly inspired from C++'s standard library [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) class template which is also misleading.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758548/825637), in C++'s standard library...

> It's called a vector because Alex Stepanov, the designer of the
>   Standard Template Library, was looking for a name to distinguish it
>   from built-in arrays. He admits now that he made a mistake, because
>   mathematics already uses the term 'vector' for a fixed-length sequence
>   of numbers.
>   ...
>   Alex's lesson: be very careful every time you name something.

Comment: C++? Unlikely in the extreme. C++ didn't even have templates until C++ 2.0 in 1989. The Revised^3 Report on the Algorithmic Language Scheme came out in 1986 and already used the term "vector" this way. I seriously doubt it was the first. The best I can gather is that the term "vector" has been used to refer to one-dimensional arrays for a long time, probably going back to early FORTRAN and APL, but I couldn't guarantee it.

Comment: @dfeuer That's good to know +1, however I'm not referring to the first appearance of the term in that context. I mean that it makes sense to me that modern languages (and packages in this case) still keep naming it as they do because of the C++ standard library; C++ is directly influencing a real lot, from what I can tell FORTAN, for example -- not so much (I'm sure it does indirectly). I'm a new blood though, so I may be completely off-based. In either case thank you, I had no idea of what you said.

Comment: Well, the thing is that Haskell and C++ are about as far from each other as any two typed programming languages can be. Haskell is a functional language (thus coming somewhat from the Lisp tradition, but more directly from Miranda, and I imagine likely influenced by ML). Haskell's type system also puts it in contact, to some degree, with the logic programming tradition, which goes back to Prolog. The combination of (relative) purity and strong typing also ties it to proof languages like Coq and Agda. C++ comes from a very different direction, more Algol, BCPL, Fortran, PL/I.

Comment: There are certainly things that cross over from one language group to another from time to time, but it seems, to me, more likely that Haskell would steal terminology from something more closely related than a distant step-cousin twice removed, when in fact more closely related languages *have* used the term "vector" in that way for many years.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want hmatrix, a Haskell interface to LAPACK and BLAS.