# Does "vector" in C++ sound strange because I am not native English speaker?

Tags: c++, vector

In C++, a vector is a container of ordered same type objects, but this is very different to the image that came into my mind, which is a segment of line plus an arrow at one end.

I feel uncomfortable about this mismatch, again and again, when I use it in C++.

[Why is a C++ Vector called a Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581426/why-is-a-c-vector-called-a-vector?s=2%7C3.5057) has a explanation, but the feeling still exist.

First lesson of http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/ has a good hint of way to think about N dimensional space, but the feeling still exist.

I guess this is because when I was young, I saw in class that line segment with arrow is marked as "a vector", and "vector" in Chinese may have different meaning and image which is different from a native English speaker's view.  And maybe the author of C++ choose to use the word "vector" and feel it is very natural and straight forward.

Could you tell me how did you learn and feel about this word "vector" in mind, in a image and intuition way, as a native English speaker?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A list of numbers in parenthesis specifying the magnitude along each dimension.

Comment: Do you also have the same feeling about "set"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No, totally not. A set is a collection like a bag with stuff in it, and these stuff can be anything, as in my mind.

Comment: `std::vector` is poorly named. Even its inventor (Alexander Stepanov) will tell you that. It has little in common with a mathematical vector.

Comment: Personally, I think it would be easier to not try to fit the idea of a C++ vector with the idea of a mathematical vector or a vector in physics. I honestly don't know if the C++ data type's name came from the math notion of a vector (though it probably did). But as far as I know there's no particular reason to make the link. It's easier - for me anyway - to think of a C++ vector as a dynamic array. Similarly, I don't have to think of why the word 'plant' can mean some sort of vegetation or mean a factory, and I don't have to get confused about how a factory and a tree might be related.

Comment: The use of "vector" to name this data type goes back to Lisp; i.e. it predates C, never mind C++

Answer (score 2):

It was answered in the thread you mentioned. But let us give it one more try.
In the plane, any "vector" (arrow) has two coordinates: x and y, so it can be written as (x, y).

In n-dimensional space, any vector has n coordinates (x1, x2, ..., xn).

Originally, the name vector in C was to designate a sequence of numbers, like above. The idea was extended to designate any sequence of "objects" having the same size.

So I suggest you read it as "coordinates of some vector", but it is in fact just a sequence of things, an array, a tableau... :)

Comment: Do you mean in the C language there's also a typical vector notion, as in C++ ?  And what does "Originally" mean, in the evolution of C++ language, or in the way that people use the vector container ?

Comment: Actually no, the vector in C is the native array ( [ ] ). I meant C++ or any language that has the "vector" notion.

Answer (score 0):

A [vector in math](http://www.math.com/tables/oddsends/vectordefs.htm) is not a segment.  It's the description of a translation movement ([magnitude and direction](http://mathinsight.org/vector_introduction)).

If you describe this [movement on a 2D plane](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gt2/TransVector.htm) into algebra, you describe an "offset" for the x coordinate and an "offset" for the y coordinate.  If you go to 3D, you have to add an offset for the z coordinate.

But in maths, spaces can be 2D, 3D, but also 4D  (add the time dimension), or [N-dimensional](http://mathinsight.org/n_dimensional_vector_examples) (that's to hard for most of the brains except for M.Hawkins to imagine).  An N dimensional vector is then represented by N offsets. If the offset is represented by a double, in C++ you'd represent this vector by a vector.

In C++ the vector generalized the mathematical concept not just to number but to any type.

Comment: So the vector notion is basically came from a math point of view, and you will feel natural AFTER you leaned N-dimensional space notion, right ?  Thanks for the triple edit to give out links :)

Comment: A lot of mathematicians object to the "magnitude and direction" description of vectors. It may be more popular among those who tolerate fuzziness in their math, but the space of real numbers is a perfectly good vector space over the field of rationals, the sequences satisfying a recurrence form a vector space, the dual of a vector space is a vector space, etc. They are poorly described by the pedagogical crutches that help a few people keep numbers and elements of R^2 or R^3 straight.