# Why do std::valarray and std::vector have swapped names?

Tags: c++, vector, valarray

First of all, I am sorry for asking a rather subjective question, but maybe there is a quite simple answer to my question.

In math when I have a vector, I can do operations on it, e.g. `v_3 = v_1 + v_2`. In c++ I can do the same with valarray. On the other side, if I just want to have an extendable array with dynamic size, I use std::vector. Do you see why I think theire names are swapped?

Is there any logical or historical explanation for this naming decision?

Comment: [Why is a C++ Vector called a Vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/581426/3953764)

Comment: Indeed; there are pertinent answers there. In summary: it's considered a historical mistake, although arguably both names are completely subjective and "vector" as a term has many, many uses across various fields so this isn't technically "wrong" or "swapped". Computer programming and maths are two different fields; even within maths, "vector" is ambiguous.

Comment: [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) is very different from `std::vector`. It's for mathematical purposes.