# Non-Constant Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create an array using a class object, and the array size can vary. What I'm doing is creating a "Library" using C++ on Visual Studio 2015, and the information comes from a text file. The first line of the file holds the number of books, and I've got the program to read the first line and set that to an integer variable. I'm trying to get a constant integer to be set as the size equal to the previous integer, but when I try to create the array, it tell's me it's not a constant.

```
int numBooks;
    inputfile >> numBooks;

    const int SIZE = numBooks;
    Library records[SIZE]; //"Expression must have a constant value"
```

What do I need to do here to get this to work. The number of books will change, so must the size of the array.

Comment: It can't work in C++. Use a std::vector. The dimension of the array must be a _compile-time_ constant, not a _run-time_ one.

Comment: use a vector...

Comment: Just use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: the vector chorus sings

Comment: Arrays of variable size are implemented in C++ by std library template class for no reason named `vector`.

Comment: You could use a pointer and new() i but yes, std::vector so you can add more books later without reallocation and copy madness.

Comment: @VTT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581426/why-is-a-c-vector-called-a-vector

Comment: @DaveS while array do decay into pointers, a pointer is not an array. The real only good suggestion here is to use std::vector.

Comment: @Rosme you're saying `Library *records = new Library[SIZE];` won't work?  Note I did recommend std::vector over it.

Comment: @DaveS I did not say it won't work. What I'm saying is that a pointer is NOT an array. But yes, I did note you recommended std::vector. I was just saying that he should not use pointers for array.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I would like to point that accepted answer there is rather misleading, readers should scroll to Mark Ruzon's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a raw array. The size of a raw array must be known at compile time. Use `std::vector` instead:

```
int numBooks;
inputfile >> numBooks;
std::vector<Library> records(numBooks);
```

Chances are that you won't need to tell the vector an initial size. Just tell it to grow with each item:

```
int numBooks;
inputfile >> numBooks;
std::vector<Library> records;
// ...
records.push_back(book);
```

Also note that `Library` is a bad name for this class. It should probably be called `Book` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
const int SIZE = numBooks;
```

Must be initialized at compile time, hence you can't initialize it.

The best alternative is to use a `std::vector`:

```
size_t numBooks;
cin >> numBooks;
std::vector<Library> records(numBooks);
```

---

**Note:**

In contrary to what [@Christian Hackl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3313064/christian-hackl) stated in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44852203/8238559), in many cases (especially with user defined types) it is better to use something along these lines:

```
size_t numBooks;
cin >> numBooks;
std::vector<Library> records;
records.reserve(numBooks);
```

and add elements there with [`std::vector::emplace_back();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

```
std::vector<Library> records(numBooks);
```

would call the default constructor for `Library` `numBooks` times and later you would come up manipulating the vector elements through copy operations or such.

[`std::vector::emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) would allow to move newly constructed `Library` records directly to the vector, and `std::vector::reserve()` will guarantee that no memory reallocation needs to take place (which could become costly performance wise).

For a large number of records read from a file that would be definitely worth to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The value of SIZE and so the size of the array is not initialized until the runtime, therefore which is not according to how C++ works.

You must assign a fixed, real integer value when initializing an array.

Use vector otherwise.